# Plumbing 2018 Uniform Plumbing Code - Need advice on adding a kitchen and dishwasher drain to laundry and clother washer drain

Tags: plumbing, vent, drain-waste-vent

**Context**: Located in California. Doing an addition and moving the kitchen. The kitchen sink and dishwasher drain into an existing line in the garage that has a laundry sink and a clothes washer. Need advice on venting, pipe size, moving the laundry sink and clothes washer.

**Existing** - Garage has a laundry sink and clothes washer on a 2in drain with a 1.5 in vent. Note the clothes washer is downstream of the vent. The laundry sink is upstream.

**New** - Adding a Kitchen Sink and Dishwasher in the Kitchen with a 2in pipe flowing into an existing garage line with laundry and clothes washer. Adding a 1.5in re-vent in the kitchen. Moving clothes washer upstream of the existing 1.5 in vent, moving laundry sink downstream of the existing vent.

Questions:

1. Could you please advice if the new setup is code?
2. Is it code to revent a new vent into an existing vent?

[image: Existing Setup]
[image: Newest Version]

Comment: I can't speak to the code compliance of the overall setup. However I will point out that this is likely a good opportunity to use an Air Admission or 'Studer' valve so that you don't need to add new vent stacks. If the existing plumbing already has enough venting, an AAV might save you a bunch of work as you won't need to tear in to walls to add the new vent stacks.

Comment: OTOH, AAVs have been noted here to fail more often than one might want and require fairly regular replacement. An actual vent, whenever possible, would be preferable.